# Algorithm for computing partial orderings of dependency graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph, dependencies, pseudocode, topological-sort

I'm trying to compute a partial "topological sort" of a dependency graph, which is actually a DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph) to be precise; so as to execute tasks without conflicting dependencies in parallel.

I came up with this simple algorithm because what I found on Google wasn't all that helpful (I keep finding only algorithms that themselves run in parallel to compute a normal topological sort).

```
visit(node)
{
    maxdist = 0;
    foreach (e : in_edge(node))
    {
        maxdist = max(maxdist, 1 + visit(source(e)))
    }
    distance[node] = maxdist;
    return distance[node];
}

make_partial_ordering(node)
{
    set all node distances to +infinite;
    num_levels = visit(node, 0);
    return sort(nodes, by increasing distance) where distances < +infinite;
}
```

(Note that this is only pseudocode and there would certainly be a few possible small optimizations)

As for the correctness, it seems pretty obvious: For the leafs (:= nodes which have no further dependency) the maximum distance-to-leaf is always 0 (correct because the loop gets skipped due to 0 edges).
For any node connected to nodes n1,..,nk the maximum distance-to-leaf is 1 + max{distance[n1],..,distance[nk]}.

I did find this article after I had written down the algorithm: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569760.aspx
But honestly, why are they doing all that list copying and so on, it just seems so really inefficient..?

Anyway I was wondering whether my algorithm is correct, and if so what it is called so that I can read up some stuff about it.

Update: I implemented the algorithm in my program and it seems to be working great for everything I tested.
Code-wise it looks like this:

```
  typedef boost::graph_traits<my_graph> my_graph_traits;
  typedef my_graph_traits::vertices_size_type vertices_size_type;
  typedef my_graph_traits::vertex_descriptor vertex;
  typedef my_graph_traits::edge_descriptor edge;

  vertices_size_type find_partial_ordering(vertex v,
      std::map<vertices_size_type, std::set<vertex> >& distance_map)
  {
      vertices_size_type d = 0;

      BOOST_FOREACH(edge e, in_edges(v))
      {
          d = std::max(d, 1 + find_partial_ordering(source(e), distance_map));
      }

      distance_map[d].insert(v);

      return d;
  }
```

Comment: You might want to reduce the worst-case from quadratic to linear by memoizing the return values of find_partial_ordering...

Comment: Do you need to find a set of layers for the graph up-front, or can you do it incrementally as the tasks execute?  If you have task execution times that vary, it is simple to create an algorithm that picks an element whose dependencies are satisfied, and then run that whenever a thread is idle.

Answer (score 16):

Your algorithm (C++) works, but it has very bad worst-case time complexity.  It computes `find_partial_ordering` on a node for as many paths as there are to that node.  In the case of a tree, the number of paths is 1, but in a general directed acyclic graph the number of paths can be exponential.

You can fix this by [memoizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) your `find_partial_ordering` results and returning without recursing when you have already computed the value for a particular node.  However, this still leaves you with a stack-busting recursive solution.

[An efficient (linear) algorithm for topological sorting is given on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Algorithms).  Doesn't this fit your needs?

Edit:  ah, I see, you want to know where the depth boundaries are so that you can parallelize everything at a given depth.  You can still use the algorithm on Wikipedia for this (and so avoid recursion).

First, Do a topological sort with the algorithm on Wikipedia. *Now* compute depths by visiting nodes in topological order:

```
depths : array 1..n
for i in 1..n
    depths[i] = 0
    for j in children of i
        depths[i] = max(depths[i], depths[j] + 1)
return depths
```

Notice that there's no recursion above, just a plain `O(|V| + |E|)` algorithm.  This has the same complexity as the algorithm on Wikipedia.